# dask count/frequency terms in column

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a very large dataset (> 10 million rows). A small 5-row example is shown below - where I am able to get Pandas do the counts of certain given terms in a column where there are lists of terms. For a single-core machine, running Pandas, things are fine. I get expected results (10 rows). But, on the same small dataset (which I am showing here) - that has 5 rows, when experiment with Dask, does the count, spits out more than 10 rows (based on number of partitions). Here is the code. Would appreciate if someone can guide me where I misunderstand/going wrong.

### Pandas Implementation:

```
def compute_total(df, term_list, cap_list):
    terms_counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['Terms']))
    terms_series = pd.Series(terms_counter)
    terms_df = pd.DataFrame({'Term': terms_series.index, 'Count': terms_series.values})
    df1 = terms_df[terms_df['Term'].isin(term_list)]
    product_terms = product(term_list, cap_list)
    df_cp = pd.DataFrame(product_terms, columns=['Terms', 'Capability'])
    tjt_df = df_cp.set_index('Terms').combine_first(df1.set_index('Term')).reset_index()
    tjt_df.rename(columns={'index': 'Term'}, inplace=True)
    tjt_df['Count'] = tjt_df['Count'].fillna(0.0)  # convert all NaN to 0.0
    return tjt_df


d = {'Title': {0: 'IRC do consider this.',
               1: 'we’re simply taking screenshot',
               2: 'Why does irc select topics?',
               3: 'Is this really a screenshot?',
               4: 'how irc is doing this?'},
     'Terms': {0: ['tech', 'channel', 'tech'],
               1: ['channel', 'findwindow', 'Italy', 'findwindow'],
               2: ['Detroit', 'topic', 'seats', 'topic'],
               3: ['tech', 'topic', 'printwindow', 'Boston', 'window'],
               4: ['privmsg', 'wheel', 'privmsg']}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
term_list = ['channel', 'topic', 'findwindow', 'printwindow', 'privmsg']
cap_list = ['irc', 'screenshot']
```

### Pandas Output:

```
          Term  Capability  Count
0      channel         irc  2.0
1      channel  screenshot  2.0
2   findwindow         irc  2.0
3   findwindow  screenshot  2.0
4  printwindow         irc  1.0
5  printwindow  screenshot  1.0
6      privmsg         irc  2.0
7      privmsg  screenshot  2.0
8        topic         irc  3.0
9        topic  screenshot  3.0
```

### Dask Implementation:

Note: For npartition, I have tried num_cores = 1, I get the expected result. If I change the num_cores to anything greater than 1, I get results that I do not understand. For eg: when num_cores = 2, the resulting df has 20 rows (ok...I get it). When num_cores = 3 or 4, I still get 20 rows. When, num_cores = 5...16, I get 40 rows! have not tried more...

```
num_cores = 8
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=num_cores * 1)
meta = make_meta({'Term': 'U', 'Capability': 'U', 'Count': 'i8'}, index=pd.Index([], 'i8'))
count_df = ddf.map_partitions(compute_total, term_list, cap_list, meta=meta).compute(scheduler='processes')
print(count_df)
print(count_df.shape)
```

### Dask Output:

```
          Term  Capability  Count
0      channel         irc    1.0
1      channel  screenshot    1.0
2   findwindow         irc    0.0
3   findwindow  screenshot    0.0
4  printwindow         irc    0.0
5  printwindow  screenshot    0.0
6      privmsg         irc    0.0
7      privmsg  screenshot    0.0
8        topic         irc    0.0
9        topic  screenshot    0.0
0      channel         irc    1.0
1      channel  screenshot    1.0
2   findwindow         irc    2.0
3   findwindow  screenshot    2.0
4  printwindow         irc    0.0
5  printwindow  screenshot    0.0
6      privmsg         irc    0.0
7      privmsg  screenshot    0.0
8        topic         irc    0.0
9        topic  screenshot    0.0
0      channel         irc    0.0
1      channel  screenshot    0.0
2   findwindow         irc    0.0
3   findwindow  screenshot    0.0
4  printwindow         irc    0.0
5  printwindow  screenshot    0.0
6      privmsg         irc    0.0
7      privmsg  screenshot    0.0
8        topic         irc    2.0
9        topic  screenshot    2.0
0      channel         irc    0.0
1      channel  screenshot    0.0
2   findwindow         irc    0.0
3   findwindow  screenshot    0.0
4  printwindow         irc    1.0
5  printwindow  screenshot    1.0
6      privmsg         irc    2.0
7      privmsg  screenshot    2.0
8        topic         irc    1.0
9        topic  screenshot    1.0
(40, 3)
```

Observation: After looking at the this rather long resulting dataframe, I think I get do one final computation on it to get what I want. Just groupby term and capability and sum. I will get the expected result (sort of).

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Term', 'Capability'])['Count'].sum()
```

But, wondering, if this can be done in a clean way using Dask. I understand that this problem is not an 'embarassingly parallel' problem - meaning, one needs to have a global view of the whole dataset to get counts. So, have to deal with it in a 'map -> reduce' fashion which I am doing now. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I think you want to use the `result` -> `gather` functions which will aggregate the results from each core. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html

Comment: @bwc I like the suggestion. Will try it. If you have an example with result/gather, please provide. Will be super helpful.